# How can I split a text cell with date and time into two separate cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to format a .csv for import somewhere, and I have a column of cells with plaintext formatted "Monday  02 23:11:52 " — I'd like to split them into two columns formatted with date (Monday, 02) and time (11:11PM)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can also use the “Text to columns” functionality:

1.Select "Text to Columns"

[image]

2.Select "Space"

[image]

3.Enter formula in cell D1:

```
=A1& " " &B1
```

[image]

4.The same way to format dates as Gary does:
[image]

Comment: This helped me solve the problem and split the columns correctly, thank you. Gary's was also helpful, though the formulas were difficult for me to follow.

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","|",2),1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","|",2))-1))
```

and in **C1** enter:

```
=TIMEVALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","|",2),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","|",2))+1,99)))
```

Then properly format **C1**:

[image]